# Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors

Tags: c#, exception, connection-string, oledb, oledbconnection

I have a problem while inserting data into an Access 2003 .mdb database.
[This solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269495) doesn't work for me!

Exception:

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation
>   generated errors. Check each OLE DB
>   status value, if available. No work
>   was done.

My connection string in `app.config` file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="UI.Properties.Settings.ZangolehDbConnectionString"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Db\ZangolehDb.mdb;"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

In my code...

UPDATED:

```
public static bool Insert(GlobalEvent globalEvent)
{
    bool result = false;
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(DataAccess.ConnectionString))
    {
        OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO UserEvents(Title, Comment, Volume, EventType, EventDate, MediaSource)VALUES(@Title, @Comment, @Volume, @EventType, @EventDate, @MediaSource)";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", globalEvent.Title);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", globalEvent.Comment);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Volume", globalEvent.Volume);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventType", globalEvent.EventType);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDate", globalEvent.EventDate);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MediaSource", globalEvent.MediaSource);
        try
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
            result = command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0; // <-- Throws Exception...
            command.Connection.Close();
        }
        catch { result = false; }
        finally
        {
            command.Connection.Close();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

It seems this is a famous problem without any answer!!! :(

Comment: NOTE: `Connection.Open();` works fine.

Comment: I would try and guess what your `INSERT` query looks like so I can help you, but I don't have my crystal ball with me right now.

Comment: You don't need Crystal Ball! I Add Insert function! :D

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is that the Long integer data type in Access is equivalent to int in C#, not long in C#

Answer (score -1):

You're passing wrong values to the query.